# I am not able to add new child entity while updating

Tags: entity-framework

I am not able to add child entity while updating through EF.

```
public virtual void TestUpdate(object item)
{
    var props = item.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().Where(x => (x.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("MIRRA"))||(x.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System.Collections.Generic.ICollection"))).Select(m => m).ToList();

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        object value = prop.GetValue(item);

        if (value is IEnumerable)
        {

            foreach (var listitem in value as IEnumerable)
            {

                TestUpdate(listitem);
            }
        }else if (value != null)
           {
            root = value;
            TestUpdate(value);

              }


    }

       int id = (int)item.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault().GetValue(item);


    if (id == 0)
    {
        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
      //add new child entity to context
    }
    else
    {
        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

at last I am saving this context but context not adding child entities

Comment: Just am iterating every entity and setting state of entity either added or modified based on primary key value . but updating an entity is working fine but adding of entity is not working

Comment: Please describe why you consider you can't add the child (is there an error message, or do you do some tests that you don't show here?).

Comment: Actually am  setting entity state as Added using EntityState.Added enum but while calling  context.savchanges() method context is updating the entities into the database but not adding new object into the database

Comment: Am trying to make generic Add or Update in this case Update is working fine adding new objects is not working .

Comment: am not getting any error i have given root object to that method it will iterate to leaf objects and try to add or update based on the condition ,update is working fine changes are reflecting into the database but new objects are not adding into the database